# How to find out programs communicate?

Tags: bots, ollydbg

I will try to explain with example;

```
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
          HWND hwndCalc;
          hwndCalc = FindWindow(NULL, "Calculator");     
          if(!hwndCalc)
                 return 1;
          SendMessage(hwndCalc, WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM(0x84, BN_CLICKED), 0);     
          return 0;     
    }
```

In calculator, when you click a button SendMessage function works. I can find it with ollydbg. But with ollydbg, I can't debug other, normal programs.(exceptions, violations, crashes...)
So i am wondering whether there is any other way to find out how programs work?

Comment: Yes, you can debug any program with a debugger.

Comment: there are many anti debug techniques. you should learn and remove these techniques. for example the most simple anti debug technique is checking isdebbugerpresent function. but you can bypass this function easily.